# Проблема с драйверами ATI

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, radeon, ati

OS: debian 7.6
    kernel: 3.2.0-4-amd64
    video: AMD nee ATI Trinity [Radeon HD 7560D] (встроенная)
    video driver: fglrx (Proprietary)
    DE: kde4

Машина не выключается, только блокируется экран, постоянно открыты 2 окна FireFox(в каждом по 20-30 вкладок), 2 окна konsole (5-8 вкладок в каждом), quanta, skype, okular, иногда OpenOffice и chrome. Где-то через 2-3 недели работы начинает появляться ошибка "Maximum number of clients reached" - при попытке запустить какое-нть X-приложение.

Что может ее вызывать? проблема с драйверами или что-то еще?

Когда была карточка nVidia - таких проблем (при таком-же режиме эксплуатации) не возникало.

Answer (score 1):

> Что может ее вызывать? проблема с драйверами или что-то еще?

возможно, разобраться поможет программа xlsclients, запущенная в эмуляторе терминала.
как явствует из её названия, она выводит список x-клиентов, подключенных к x-серверу.

Comment: `xlsclients | wc -l
Maximum number of clients reachedxlsclients:  unable to open display ":0"`

Если закрыть что-нть, то :
`xlsclients | wc -l
77`

Итого - 77 X-приложений - и опаньки

Comment: вы перечислили семь программ: firefox, konsole, quanta, skype, okular, openoffice, chrome. т.е., должно быть семь x-клиентов, а не 77. смотрите, что это за «лишние» клиенты: возможно, какая-то из программ «плодит» дополнительные подключения к x-серверу.

Comment: ну то, что я перечислил - это приложения, которые, скажем так, перед глазами. остальное - это plasma-desktop, knotify4, kwin, krunner, kuiserver и прочие kde-компоненты. я думаю их список примерно одинаков для любой kde-системы. Тот-же skype - порождает 7 записей в списке xlsclients, okular - 3 записи. 
На домашней машине (идентичной и по версиям ПО и по варианту использования, за исключением видео - там Nvidia) такой проблемы не возникает.

Comment: проверьте, не накапливаются ли открытые сокеты (скорее всего, из-за «падений» каких-нибудь сбоящих x-клиентов): sudo lsof -p $(pidof Xorg X) | grep socket | wc -l

Comment: эта проверка выдает 0

Comment: возможно, на предыдущих шагах что-то неверно. можно начать с проверки, выдаёт ли программа pidof process_id x-сервера.

Comment: Да - pidof выдает верный идентификатор процесса. сейчас проверил дома xlsclients  - 107 Х-приложений - и все норм.

Comment: в debian x-сервер собран с поддержкой 256 клиентских подключений (grep MAXCLIENTS /usr/include/xorg/misc.h).

Comment: нашёл, как посмотреть текущие процессы, подключившиеся к x-серверным сокетам: sudo ss -x src /tmp/.X11-unix/*; если их значительно меньше 256, вероятно, какие-то x-клиенты не закрывают корректно открытое подключение (вызовом XCloseDisplay). как вычислить таких клиентов мне (пока) в голову не пришло. разве что анализировать текущие подключения и сообщения об ошибках в ~/.xsession-errors.